# Add A Custom CSS Class To Main Menu Link

Tags: css, toplinks

Is their a way to add a custom class to one link within the main navigation?

For example I would like the category "SALE" to be coloured red and be bold.

Is this possible?

Many Thanks

Comment: @ToonVanDooren They are all bad solutions, as you'd want a top menu in a CMS to be dynamic. To target nth-child or nav-n is bad practice, as all will fall apart when client adds another menu item.

Answer (score 2):

Each menu item has a unique class name `nav-1`, `nav-2`, `nav-1-1`. Use those ones.
Check what nav class your menu item has using firebug.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! - I will add CSS to for example: #menu11. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the already existing class to select only the main menu,

For example,

```
.parentMenu a span {
color: red;
font-weight: bold
}
```

and for the particular menu, may use nth child selector in css.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mozilla firebug to select the element & identify the css associated with that. Then change the css properties.

Answer (score 1):

**using jQuery**

> jQuery("#nav li.nav-1").addClass( "myClass yourClass" );

change nav-1 to your menu class and make css.

[image]